# Get unique keys only from javascript array, where keys and value both are dynamic

Tags: javascript, json, object

This is my object-

```
[{"index":"style_bags","name":"24"},
{"index":"style_bags","name":"25"},
{"index":"style_bags","name":"26"},
{"index":"category_gear","name":"90"},
{"index":"category_gear","name":"98"},
{"index":"price","name":"400-"}]
```

This is expected -

```
[{"index":"style_bags","name":"26"},
{"index":"category_gear","name":"98"},
{"index":"price","name":"400-"}]
```

Requirement is to get last value and key pair from object in javascript.

As per asked from Certain Performance The way I reached here was through this code -

```
if(href.indexOf("&") >= 0){
                    var hrefSplit = href.split('&');
                }
                if(!(href.indexOf("&") >= 0)){
                    var hrefSplit = href.split('?'); 
                    var hrefSplit2 = hrefSplit[1].split('=');                            
                }

                params.push({ index: hrefSplit2[0], name:  hrefSplit2[1]});

                var i = 0;

                jquery.each(params, function( index, value ) {

                    var key = value.index;

                    if(hrefSplit2[0] == key){
                        i++;                        
                    }  

                });

                valueGet.push({ index: hrefSplit2[0], name:  hrefSplit2[1]});
```

I am not a javascript pro, so was kind of blank on how to proceed further.

Comment: `Requirement is` Have you made any attempt at all yet?

Comment: Actually this is a magento requirment, And I have worked for the last 4 hour to make it this format, and needed some help. If you know magento is crazy. So whatever I did so far would be useless posting here, as it was magento code.

Comment: Please show the code you've tried, thanks

Comment: I have added the steps on how I reached there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will make a temp object storing the last found values and then create the resulting array.

```js
let tempObj = {}

let srcArray = [
{"index":"style_bags","name":"24"},
{"index":"style_bags","name":"25"},
{"index":"style_bags","name":"26"},
{"index":"category_gear","name":"90"},
{"index":"category_gear","name":"98"},
{"index":"price","name":"400-"}];

for (let item of srcArray) {
  tempObj[item.index] = item.name
}

let result = Object.keys(tempObj).map(index => {
  return {
    index,
    name: tempObj[index]
  }
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to create an object and then `Object.values` to get array of values. It will get last object based on `index` property.

```js
const data = [{"index":"style_bags","name":"24"}, {"index":"style_bags","name":"25"}, {"index":"style_bags","name":"26"}, {"index":"category_gear","name":"90"}, {"index":"category_gear","name":"98"}, {"index":"price","name":"400-"}]

const result = data.reduce((r, e) => Object.assign(r, {[e.index]: e}), {})
console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and collect the last object with the same index property.

```js
var array = [{ index: "style_bags", name: "24" }, { index: "style_bags", name: "25" }, { index: "style_bags", name: "26" }, { index: "category_gear", name: "90" }, { index: "category_gear", name: "98" }, { index: "price", name: "400-" }],
    result = [...new Map(array.map(o => [o.index, o])).values()];
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the verified answer exactly gave the response I needed. Thanks for your time though.

Answer (score 1):

You inspired me to update my [javascript linq library](https://github.com/biggyspender/loq) to support `.last()`. So, using this library, you could:

```js
var list = [{"index":"style_bags","name":"24"},
    {"index":"style_bags","name":"25"},
    {"index":"style_bags","name":"26"},
    {"index":"category_gear","name":"90"},
    {"index":"category_gear","name":"98"},
    {"index":"price","name":"400-"}];

var filtered = loq(list).groupBy(x => x.index).select(g => g.last());
console.log(filtered.toArray());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/biggyspender/loq/cb4e5cb4/lib/loq.min.js"></script>
```